# Hadoop NFS mount issue

Tags: linux, hadoop, hdfs, nfs

I'm trying to mount an NFS share from windows server 2012 onto my Hadoop cluster (running Hadoop 2.7.3), so it can run MapReduce on files uploaded to the Windows Server. The Hadoop cluster is running on raspberry pi 2 (8 of them), and I've already gone through the configuration on the Hadoop [wiki](https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r2.7.3/hadoop-project-dist/hadoop-hdfs/HdfsNfsGateway.html)

I've tried mounting the NFS onto the HDFS dir (/hdfs/tmp/datanode) on the master, but it isn't accessible on the namenodes.

Am I mounting it in the wrong place?

Answer (score 0):

Nevermind, I've changed my solution to have the NFS mount onto the namenode, and a crontab script puts files onto hdfs as it needs them

```
#! /bin/bash
inotifywait -mr -e create --format '%w%f' /hdfs-nfs/* | while read NEWFILE; do
    echo "${NEWFILE} detected"
    hadoop fs -put "${NEWFILE}" /
done
```